# PhpMyAdmin No Drop Database Option + SQL Drop Commands Disabled

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, sql-drop

I have tried altering config.default.php, config.inc.php, common.inc.php, to include $cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = true;  none of this results in the Drop Database option tab.  When I try to use SQL statements directly I get a message that they are disabled. Version 3.5.8.2 phpMyAdmin running on shared host - NOT wamp.  What else is there to try?

Comment: Why is it so difficult to just write 3 words? `DROP DATABASE theDatabase`? Do you have permissions?

Comment: @r3mus I don't read more than one sentence. What's wrong with the second part of my comment?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO permissions may or may not be the problem? Give a suggestion to try? As it stands, if I was new to the php/mysql environment, your comment wouldn't be remotely helpful.

Comment: @r3mus few of my comments are remotely helpful

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO that's a really great attitude for StackOverflow :|

Comment: It's to keep up with the amount of bad questions.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: even typing the command in phpMyAdmin (as the poster wrote) will be intercepted if the directive is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

3.5.8.2 is somewhat outdated; you should try to update to the 4.x version if possible. However, what you're trying should work.

To be clear, config.inc.php is the proper file to modify (in the root phpMyAdmin folder). You can add a line like

```
die("config.inc.php is being read properly");
```

to the end of config.inc.php to make sure you're actually editing the proper file.

Although I don't have an installation that old to test one, I think the DROP DATABASE link is shown in the Operations tab; are you sure you're looking in the right place? Are you sure this user has the proper permissions within MySQL? You can check what permissions a user has through the Users tab (which I think is "Privileges" in 3.5.x).

Comment: I confirm that in 3.5.8.2 there is no Drop option tab; the link is under the database Operations tab. Ensure you have restarted your browser after editing config.inc.php.